# Flattening BibTeX files

Tags: bibtex

Is there a tool that "flattens" a complicated BibTeX file?

In particular, I would like to:

1. Expand `@STRING` macros, for example:

   ```
   @STRING{foo = {Bar}}
   @MISC{x, title = foo}
   ```

   ⇓

   ```
   @MISC{x, title = {Bar}}
   ```
2. Expand cross references, for example:

   ```
   @INPROCEEDINGS{x, title = {A}, crossref = y}
   @PROCEEDINGS{y, title = {B}, booktitle = {B}}
   ```

   ⇓

   ```
   @INPROCEEDINGS{x, title = {A}, booktitle = {B}}
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be performed by the `bib2bib` tool, which provides pretty flexible and reliable ways to filter/extract/expand bibtex entries. This (little known) utility is part of the [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) tool suite. (Note: you have to look for the **PDF** documentation, the HTML documentation does not discuss `bib2bib`!)

For instance, to flatten a `bib` file, one just writes:

```
bib2bib --expand --expand-xrefs -ob flattened.bib original.bib
```

It is also possible to specify filter and sorting options.
Multiple conditions can be grouped and combined with and/or/not to extract only entries matching certain criteria.

**Edit:** One thing that apparently is not supported is filtering out `@comment` entries. These entries are, for instance, inserted by JabRef. To get rid of them just pipe the result through some regex tool. Jukka suggested `perl -p0 -e 's/\s*(\@comment\{\{[^}]*\}\}\s*)+/\n\n/g'` for the job.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need; being able to flatten and filter with the same tool is great! There is one problem, though: `bib2bib` seems to preserve all `@comment` entries, no matter what I do. Even if I use the filtering options, I seem to always get all `@comment` entries...

Comment: Right, it even adds some `@comment` entries. If your `@comment` entries are single-line only (like those added by `bib2bib` itself), you may just filter the resulting file through sed/grep/awk to get rid of them, e.g. `grep -v "@comment" flattened.bib > nocomment.bib`.

Comment: You can use `--no-comment` to prevent `bib2bib` from adding any more comments, but it still preserves all existing comments. In my case I have lots of multi-line comments that are created by JabRef, and they are a bit more tricky to filter out...

Comment: (Of course this is not an unsolvable problem. For example, something like `perl -p0 -e 's/\s*(\@comment\{\{[^}]*\}\}\s*)+/\n\n/g'` happens to work in my specific case.)

Comment: Does anyone have guidance as to how I can install bib2bib? Their instructions are not working for me. Alternatively, perhaps there is a different software that accomplishes the same goal?