# when multiple entries crossref the same proceeding, the proceeding details are not printed, but cited!

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I actually have the exact opposite of this problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54799/for-child-entries-with-crossrefs-how-can-i-instruct-biblatex-to-output-only-a-r).

When one entry (`@inproceedings`) crossref-erences a proceeding, all is fine. Only the `@inproceedings` entry is in the list of references, and it inherits all the details of the proceedings.

However, when more than one entry (`@inproceedings`) crossref-erence the same proceeding, then both entries PLUS the proceedings are in the list of references, the two `@inproceedings` contain a reference to the proceedings, which is not what I want. I would like each `@inproceedings` to print the details of the proceedings (editor, year, etc.).

Here is the bib file my.bib:

```
@inproceedings{inproc1,
title = {Paper 1},
author = {Authors of Paper 1},
pages = {40--46},
crossref = {Proc},
}
@inproceedings{inproc2,
author = {Paper 2},
title = {Authors of Paper 2},
pages = {47--52},
crossref = {Proc},
}
@proceedings{Proc,
editor = {Editor Name},
title = {Proceedings title},
booktitle = {Proceedings title},
year = {2015},
}
```

And here is the basic latex file loading this bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{inproc1,inproc2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{my.bib}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output I get.

[image]

What I would like, however, is to delete the second reference (the proceedings), which I never reference, and print its details (the editors, year, etc.) within the first and third entries.

Is there anything that can be done from *within* the bib file to fix this?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the behavior you have observed is *by design* and the actual purpose of splitting `@inproceedings` and `@proceedings` entries: If you cite a paper (`@inproceedings` entry), BibTeX will either import the missing information from the crossref'ed `@proceedings` entry into the paper's entry inside the bibliography or, if more than two papers from the same proceedings are cited, save some space by putting the `@proceedings` entry itself into the bibliography and refer from the paper's entries to them.

**Recommended solution**

The threshold of two is just the default: It is configurable on the `bibtex` command line with the `-min-crossrefs=NUMBER` option. So if you change your `bibtex` command line to

```
bibtex -min-crossrefs=99 mytex.aux
```

all `@inproceedings` entries will be expanded inside the bibliography.

**Solution within the bib file**

However, as you have asked for an option to change this within the `bib` file itself: This is possible by not using `@crossref`, but writing the relevant information from the `@proceedings` entry directly into each `@inproceedings` entry:

```
@inproceedings{inproc1,
title = {Paper 1},
author = {Authors of Paper 1},
pages = {40--46},
editor = {Editor Name},
booktitle = {Proceedings title},
year = {2015},
}
@inproceedings{inproc2,
author = {Paper 2},
title = {Authors of Paper 2},
pages = {47--52},
editor = {Editor Name},
booktitle = {Proceedings title},
year = {2015},
}
@proceedings{Proc,
editor = {Editor Name},
title = {Proceedings title},
booktitle = {Proceedings title},
year = {2015},
}
```

However, I recommend to *not* change your master bib file in this way – the way back is much more work! Instead, use some tool like `bib2bib` to [create a flattened variant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31381/3751) of your bib file.